# Getting a list of shared drives on a remote computer that has Windows 7 from a computer with Windows 10 in PowerShell

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, powershell, network-shares

I need to get a list of shared drives on a remote computer that has Windows 7 from a host PC with Windows 10 in PowerShell. I already tried the following in PowerShell ISE as both an admin and a standard user.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -computer <computername> | select name, providername
```

This method didn't work.

Comment: What is the exact error you get? If you use PowerShell remoting, does that work? (You can use icm for that)

Comment: Are both computers part of a domain?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the correct class is

> get-WmiObject -class Win32_Share -node

*(where node is the Computer Name or IP Address)*

You should provide any error messages you get and some context (i.e. are the computers joined to the same domain? Are they connected to the same physical network?)

Also, make sure user permissions and firewall settings are compatible with what you're trying to do.

Have a look here:
[PowerShell Get List Of Folders Shared](https://superuser.com/questions/769679/powershell-get-list-of-folders-shared)