# windows get file list of shares of local network host

Tags: windows, network-shares, directory-listing

The local network contains a few file server that each has multiple shares.

I would like to get a complete recursive directory listing for a given host.
Unfortunately `dir /S /B \\servername` does not work.

I would have to call `dir /S /B \\servername\share` for each share separately.

Is there a more easy way?

Also the process should not stop or abort if directory has no access rights.

Comment: You can start by looking at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/769679/powershell-get-list-of-folders-shared).

Comment: thank you. that link helps. however it seems it is not feasable to do without `net view` and result parsing

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell one-liner will list all the shares of the specified computer, and
for each share will list all its files:

```
foreach($Share in Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -ComputerName 'COMPUTER') {Get-ChildItem "\\$($Share.__SERVER)\$($Share.Name)"}
```

You may all invoke it from a Command Prompt (cmd) or batch (`.bat`) as:

```
powershell "foreach($Share in Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -ComputerName 'COMPUTER') {Get-ChildItem "\\$($Share.__SERVER)\$($Share.Name)"}" >\path\outfile.txt
```

EDIT

For querying a non-Windows server, the problem is that the above
requires an RPC server which is not available.

You might try using WMIC instead. Enter in the PowerShell command prompt
the following two lines for one such Linux server:

```
$allshares = (net view \\SERVER) | % { if($_.IndexOf(' Disk ') -gt 0){ $_.Split('  ')[0] }}
foreach ($Share in $allshares) {Get-ChildItem "\\SERVER\\$Share"}
```

Comment: that does not work. this gives error that there is no RPC server that can execute wmi-requests (the server are either simple NAS or some other linux based file servers). it seems that there is no way around `net view server` and parsing the result with some script language

Comment: It worked for me. Perhaps the difference is that a firewall is blocking your RPC. The ports are 135 and dynamic ports above 1024. Perhaps [this link](https://www.dell.com/support/article/au/en/audhs1/sln283117/troubleshooting-rpc-server-unavailable-errors?lang=en) might be useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: since some are not a windows machine they do not have a RPC service that answe WMI-Reqests

Comment: I added an alternative syntax that uses WMIC instead. Try to see if it works better.

Comment: I hoped that there would a simple command. I knew the `net view` approach but it has a lot of gotchas: `net view` is localized and its output depends on the language settings. in German Windows eg. `Disk` is translated `Plattte`. My implemented approach is looking for the delimiter line, go two up, look at which character the second column starts and how long the line is and then checking in each following line if the the line length matches and the last character of the first column is a space because splitting at Space is also not possible (white spaces in share names)

Answer (score -1):

through explorer open the folder containing the shares. Hold shift and right click.
Choose open powershell or cmd here and type: dir > textfile.txt

Comment: this would create a file on the remote server that may not even be possible. but beside from this, this is exactly that i suggested in the "I would have to call...." sentence

Answer (score -1):

Create a text file called `C:\Folders.txt`

Run this in Powershell :

```powershell
Get-ChildItem "\\192.168.2.4\Home" -Recurse -Name -Directory | Out-File "C:\Folders.txt"
```

Comment: but this already accessed the share `Home`. my question is about only passing a host name. your answer is identical to my `dir /AD /S /B \\somehost\Home` (and i do not even want the `/AD`)